# Unable to <img src> google apis

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

I am trying to get an image from Google Storage API
hence I used this line of code in my html

```
<img src="http://storage.googleapis.com/property_home_image/1405009694204ioiqlxmseplcn.jpg"/>
```

However, I get an error message on my console for chrome, which is

```
GET http://storage.googleapis.com/property_home_image/1405009694204ioiqlxmseplcn.jpg net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION
```

It works fine all on all browsers except for Chrome, may I know how I am able to solve such issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1405009694204ioiqlxmseplcn.jpg` does not exist in the `property_home_image` bucket.